# PostgreSQL + PostGIS - Recortar polígono com outro polígono e trazer as duas partes dos recorte

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Boa tarde!

Preciso recortar um polígono A por um outro polígono B usando PostgreSQL, de forma que:

1. Na área de interseção entre o poligono A e B, eu tenha como resultado a interseção, todos os atributos de A e todos os atributos de B.
2. Na área onde não há interseção, o meu resultado final deve ser a diferença entre o Polígono A e o polígono B, todos os atributos de A, e os atributos de B nulos.

Segue uma imagem de exemplo:
[image: EXEMPLO]

O restante do polígono B pode ser ignorado.

Já tentei fazer um LEFT JOIN das das tabelas usando como condição o ST_Intersects, MAS, dessa forma, os polígonos na tabela A que não tiverem nenhuma interseção com B serão sumariamente ignorados, e eu preciso trazê-los inteiros, com os atributos de B nulos.

Já tentei fazer uma junção simples:

```
case 
ST_Intersects(a.geom,b.geom) = false
then a.cor, a.tamanho, ST_Difference(a.geom,b.geom)
else a.cor, a.tamanho, b.forma, ST_Intersection(a.geom,b.geom)
end
```

Só que dessa forma, quando HÁ interseção, eu estou tendo como resultado somente a parte da interseção, e não ambos os recortes.

Uma luz?